# How to fix a data fetching function in python using sql query?

Tags: python, sql, data-science, analytics, dremio

I have developed a function which uses parametrized sql based on user input to fetch records. However, I am facing a type mismatch problem in the where clause of the query. please help me fix it.
Start_Date and End_Date are string stype whereas record_date is datetime64[ns].
The Error is stating the the comparison between record_date and start_date and end_date has a type mismatch.

Comment: start_date = input("Enter start date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
months = int(input("Enter number of months: "))
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=months)
start_date = str(start_date.date())
end_date = str(end_date.date())
    sql_A = f"""
        SELECT
               a.record_date,
a.x
               
        FROM edm.dm_{brand_name} a
        LEFT JOIN edm.dm_{brand_name}_x b ON a.x = b.x AND a.record_date = b.record_date
        WHERE a.record_date >='{start_date}' AND a.record_date <= '{end_date}'
    """

Comment: Hi, you can use the to_date function in sql to convert your string to a database date https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp. That a little bit differnt for each sql Database type (Postgres /Mysql ...)

The best way would be to let your database framwork handle that and use proper parameters. An sqlalchemy example would be here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_core_using_textual_sql.htm

Comment: not working bro

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you tagged Dremio, Dremio doesn't support parameterized queries at the moment (up to version 24), but that should eventually be supported.